# Flutter Error: "cm", The argument type ,ContextModel can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ContextModel

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

### Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:math_expressions/math_expressions.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as Path;

import './calculator_buttons.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const CalculatorApp());
  //void evaluate;
}

class CalculatorApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const CalculatorApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CalculatorAppState createState() => _CalculatorAppState();
}

class _CalculatorAppState extends State<CalculatorApp> {
  int firstNum = 0;
  int secondNum = 0;
  String history = '';
  String texttodisplay = '';
  String res = '';
  String operation = '';
  ///
  void numClick(String text) {
    setState(() => texttodisplay += text);
  }

  void allClear(String text) {
    setState(() {
      history = '';
      texttodisplay = '';
    });
  }

  void clear(String text) {
    setState(() {
      texttodisplay = '';
    });
  }

  void evaluate(String text) {
    Parser p = Parser();
    Expression exp = p.parse(texttodisplay);
    ContextModel cm = ContextModel();
    //double eval = exp.evaluate(EvaluationType.REAL, cm);
    //cm.bindVariable
    //double eval = exp.evaluate(EvaluationType.REAL, cm);

    setState(() {
      history = texttodisplay;
      texttodisplay = exp.evaluate(EvaluationType.REAL, cm);
    });
  }
```

**"cm" The argument type 'ContextModel can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ContextModel.**

### Error

> The argument type 'ContextModel (where ContextModel is defined in C:\Users\asus\Documents\calculator\lib\main.dart)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ContextModel (where ContextModel is defined in C:\Android app development\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\math_expressions-2.1.1\lib\src\evaluator.dart)'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
> main.dart(395, 7): ContextModel is defined in C:\Users\asus\Documents\calculator\lib\main.dart
> evaluator.dart(22, 60): ContextModel is defined in C:\Android app development\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\math_expressions-2.1.1\lib\src\evaluator.dart
> ContextModel cm

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that `ContextModel` is being re defined in the file `main.dart`. Are you sure `cm` is being assign an instance of the `ContextModel` of the `math_expressions` package?

To be sure, Visual Studio Code and Android Studio should lead you to the definition of the element if you pres ctrl+click, try pressing in `ContextModel`.

Also can try debugging, put a breakpoint after `cm` and see what is being assign.